# App Service backup fails after changing DB pricing from DTU to vCore

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple App Services running under the same App Service plan and accessing one SQL databases each in the same SQL elastic pool.
All apps are configured to perform a daily backup including the database.
This worked fine until I changed the pricing plan of the SQL elastic pool from DTU (Standard) to vCore (Gen4). Since then I only get the following message and the backup fails:

> Create Database copy of MyDB (MyDB_7dd79ad1_00af_42d9_85f6_5e011b67d765) threw an exception. Could not create Database copy. Make sure to use the admin user in the database connection string.

The connection string is using the admin user (I also tried a new dbmanger user with the same result). Using SSMS or other backup tools I can create backups of the DB with the same user.

Does anyone know how I can fix that so my backups are running again?
(if I exclude the DB they are still running fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the/a solution:
If I take the databases out of the SQL elastic pool and then add them right back into the pool the backups are working again...